# ssh/sftp с python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Есть необходимость периодически скачивать файлы с удаленного сервера. При этом нет прямого доступа. Приходиться идти через несколько узлов. Можно ли (если да то как) организовать это в Python c paramiko или др модулем?
пробовал открывать новое соединение в уже имеющемся, итог - падение с таймаутом подключения.

```py
import paramiko 

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
with client.connect(hostname=host1, username=user1, password=secret1) as con1:
    client2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client2.connect(hostname=host2, username=user2, password=secret2)
    ....
    ....
    client2.close()
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что наличие контекста с конструкцией `with` как-то связывает один `SSHClient` с другим (если только такое не описано прямо в документации). Боюсь, что задачу можно решить только через изначальное подключение к первому хосту по `paramiko`, а дальше ssh консольными командами. Это немножко дичь, но если очень надо, того норм. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь подскажет более адекватный вариант `:)`

Comment: такую 'дичь' я знаю(учитывая что узлов там больше 2, это совсем беда) в поисках адекватного варианта я и пришел)

Comment: Пропишите в конфигурации SSH клиента создание мастер-соединения. Тогда все новые попытки будут просто идти по уже открытому, если оно есть.